# Finding specific value in list

Tags: python, list

Hi guys having a little issue with part of my code

So if for example

```
target_list = []
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4]
target = 4
if target in lst:
    target_list.append(lst.index(target))
return target_list
```

I want the it to return:

```
[3, 4, 6]
```

I think the problem has to do with .index(target) only takes the first target of the list. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` to keep track of the index and use list comprehension with `if` to filter and extract the index corresponding to specific value:

```
[i for i, v in enumerate(lst) if v == 4]
# [3, 4, 6]
```

---

With a normal loop, you will need to initialize a index list and append the index to it if the value is target:

```
index = []
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i] == 4:
        index.append(i)

index
# [3, 4, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you that works, although my beginner class hasn't learned about enumerate, is there a more clear alternative for a beginner?

Comment: We have learned loops but not list comprehensions or recursive